# Java escape Html special Chars

Tags: java, html, performance, escaping

how would I make this method nicer:

```
String l = text;

    // System.out.println("startet UmlautAnpassen");
    l = l.replaceAll("$", "usd");
    l = l.replaceAll("�", "xxx");
    l = l.replaceAll("", "xxx");
    l = l.replaceAll("Ã„", "ä");
    l = l.replaceAll("Ã–", "ü");
    l = l.replaceAll("Ãœ", "ö");
    l = l.replaceAll("Ã¤", "Ä");
    l = l.replaceAll("Ã¶", "Ü");
    l = l.replaceAll("Ã¼", "Ö");
    l = l.replaceAll("ÃŸ", "ß");






    if (l.contains("&#") && l.contains(";")) {

        if ((l.contains("&#x") || l.contains("&#X")) && l.contains(";")) {
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]20;", " ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]21;", "!");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]22;", "\"");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]23;", "#");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]24;", "usd");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]25;", "%");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]26;", "&");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]27;", "'");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]28;", "(");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]29;", ")");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]2A;", "*");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]2B;", "+");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]2C;", ",");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]2D;", "-");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]2E;", ".");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]2F;", "/");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]30;", "0");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]31;", "1");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]32;", "2");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]33;", "3");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]34;", "4");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]35;", "5");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]36;", "6");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]37;", "7");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]38;", "8");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]39;", "9");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]3A;", ":");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]3B;", ";");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]3C;", "<");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]3D;", "=");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]3E;", ">");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]3F;", "?");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]40;", "@");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]41;", "A");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]42;", "B");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]43;", "C");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]44;", "D");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]45;", "E");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]46;", "F");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]47;", "G");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]48;", "H");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]49;", "I");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]4A;", "J");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]4B;", "K");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]4C;", "L");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]4D;", "M");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]4E;", "N");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]4F;", "O");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]50;", "P");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]51;", "Q");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]52;", "R");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]53;", "S");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]54;", "T");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]55;", "U");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]56;", "V");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]57;", "W");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]58;", "X");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]59;", "Y");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]5A;", "Z");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]5B;", "(");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]5C;", "\\/");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]5D;", ")");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]5E;", "^");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]5F;", "_");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]60;", " ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]61;", "a");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]62;", "b");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]63;", "c");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]64;", "d");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]65;", "e");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]66;", "f");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]67;", "g");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]68;", "h");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]69;", "i");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]6A;", "j");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]6B;", "k");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]6C;", "l");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]6D;", "m");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]6E;", "n");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]6F;", "o");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]70;", "p");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]71;", "q");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]72;", "r");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]73;", "s");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]74;", "t");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]75;", "u");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]76;", "v");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]77;", "w");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]78;", "x");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]79;", "y");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]7A;", "z");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]7B;", "(");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]7C;", "/");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]7D;", ")");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]7E;", "~");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][aA]0;", " ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][aA]1;", "¡");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][aA]2;", "cent");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][aA]3;", "gbf");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][aA]5;", "yen");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][aA]7;", "§");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][aA]9;", "copyright");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][aA][bB]\\;", "<<");

            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][aA][dD]\\;", "");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][aA][eE]\\;", "reg");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][bB]0;", "°");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][bB]1;", "+/-");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][bB]2;", "^2");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][bB]3;", "^3");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][bB]5;", "micro");

            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][bB]7;", "-");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][bB]8;", ",");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][bB]9;", "^1");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][bB][aA];", "º");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][bB][bB];", ">>");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][bB][cC];", "1/4");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][bB][dD];", "1/2");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][bB][eE];", "3/4");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][bB][fF];", "¿");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][cC]0;", "À");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][cC]1;", "Á");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][cC]2;", "Â");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][cC]3;", "Â");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][cC]4;", "Ä");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][cC]5;", "Å");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][cC]6;", "Æ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][cC]7;", "Ç");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][cC]8;", "È");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][cC]9;", "É");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][cC][aA];", "Ê");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][cC][bB];", "Ë");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][cC][cC];", "Ì");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][cC][dD];", "Í");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][cC][eE];", "Î");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][cC][fF];", "Ï");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][dD]0;", "Ð");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][dD]1;", "Ñ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][dD]2;", "Ò");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][dD]3;", "Ó");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][dD]4;", "Ô");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][dD]5;", "Õ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][dD]6;", "Ö");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][dD]7;", "×");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][dD]8;", "Ø");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][dD]9;", "Ù");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][dD][aA];", "Ú");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][dD][bB];", "Û");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][dD][cC];", "Ü");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][dD][dD];", "Ý");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][dD][eE];", "Þ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][dD][fF];", "ß");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][eE]0;", "à");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][eE]1;", "á");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][eE]2;", "â");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][eE]3;", "ã");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][eE]4;", "ä");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][eE]5;", "å");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][eE]6;", "æ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][eE]7;", "ç");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][eE]8;", "è");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][eE]9;", "é");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][eE][aA];", "ê");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][eE][bB];", "ë");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][eE][cC];", "ì");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][eE][dD];", "í");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][eE][eE];", "î");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][eE][fF];", "ï");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][fF]0;", "ð");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][fF]1;", "ñ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][fF]2;", "ò");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][fF]3;", "ó");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][fF]4;", "ô");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][fF]5;", "õ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][fF]6;", "ö");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][fF]7;", "÷");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][fF]8;", "ø");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][fF]9;", "ù");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][fF][aA];", "ú");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][fF][bB];", "û");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][fF][cC];", "ü");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][fF][dD];", "ý");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][fF][eE];", "þ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX][fF][fF];", "ÿ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#[xX]\\w{2};", " ");
        } // end if ((l.contains("&#[xX]") || l.contains("&#X"))||
            // l.contains(";"))

        if (l.contains("&#") && l.contains(";")) {
            l = l.replaceAll("&#131;", "ƒ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#133;", "...");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#138;", "Š");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#137;", "promille");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#140;", "Œ");

            l = l.replaceAll("&#154;", "š");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#156;", "œ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#160;", " ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#161;", "¡");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#162;", "cent");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#163;", "gbf");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#165;", "yen");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#167;", "§");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#169;", "copyright");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#171;", "<<");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#173;", "");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#174;", "reg");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#176;", "°");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#177;", "+/-");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#178;", "^2");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#179;", "^3");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#180;", " ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#181;", "micro");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#184;", ",");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#185;", "^1");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#186;", "º");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#187;", ">>");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#188;", "1/4");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#189;", "1/2");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#190;", "3/4");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#191;", "¿");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#192;", "À");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#193;", "Á");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#194;", "Â");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#195;", "Ã");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#196;", "Ä");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#197;", "Å");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#198;", "Æ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#199;", "Ç");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#200;", "È");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#201;", "É");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#202;", "Ê");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#203;", "Ë");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#204;", "Ì");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#205;", "Í");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#206;", "Î");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#207;", "Ï");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#208;", "Ð");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#209;", "Ñ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#210;", "Ò");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#211;", "Ó");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#212;", "Ô");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#213;", "Õ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#214;", "Ö");

            l = l.replaceAll("&#215;", "x");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#216;", "Ø");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#217;", "Ù");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#218;", "Ú");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#219;", "Û");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#220;", "Ü");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#221;", "Ý");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#222;", "Þ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#223;", "ß");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#224;", "à");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#225;", "á");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#226;", "â");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#227;", "ã");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#228;", "ä");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#229;", "å");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#230;", "æ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#231;", "ç");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#232;", "è");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#233;", "é");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#234;", "ê");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#235;", "ë");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#236;", "ì");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#237;", "í");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#238;", "î");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#239;", "ï");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#240;", "ð");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#241;", "ñ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#242;", "ò");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#243;", "ó");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#244;", "ô");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#245;", "õ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#246;", "ö");

            l = l.replaceAll("&#247;", "÷");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#248;", "ø");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#249;", "ù");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#250;", "ú");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#251;", "û");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#252;", "ü");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#253;", "ý");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#254;", "þ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#255;", "ÿ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#34;", "\"");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#38;", "&");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#60;", "<");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#62;", ">");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#039;", "\'");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#8482;", "eur");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#8730;", "/");
            l = l.replaceAll("&#\\d{2,5};", " ");
        } // end if (l.contains("&#") && l.contains(";"))

        if (l.contains("&") && l.contains(";")) {
            l = l.replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&iexcl;", "¡");
            l = l.replaceAll("&cent;", "cent");
            l = l.replaceAll("&pound;", "gbf");
            l = l.replaceAll("&yen;", "yen");
            l = l.replaceAll("&euro;", "eur");
            l = l.replaceAll("&copy;", "copyright");
            l = l.replaceAll("&laquo;", "<<");
            l = l.replaceAll("&reg;", "reg");
            l = l.replaceAll("&deg;", "°");
            l = l.replaceAll("&plusmn;", "+/-");
            l = l.replaceAll("&permill;", "promille");
            l = l.replaceAll("&micro;", "micro");
            l = l.replaceAll("&radic;", "wurzel");
            l = l.replaceAll("&ordm;", "º");
            l = l.replaceAll("&raquo;", ">>");
            l = l.replaceAll("&frac14;", "1/4");
            l = l.replaceAll("&frac12;", "1/2");
            l = l.replaceAll("&frac34;", "3/4");
            l = l.replaceAll("&iquest;", "¿");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Agrave;", "À");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Aacute;", "Á");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Acirc;", "Â");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Atilde;", "Ã");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Auml;", "Ä");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Aring;", "Å");
            l = l.replaceAll("&AElig;", "Æ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Ccedil;", "Ç");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Egrave;", "È");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Eacute;", "É");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Ecirc;", "Ê");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Euml;", "Ë");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Igrave;", "Ì");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Iacute;", "Í");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Icirc;", "Î");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Iuml;", "Ï");
            l = l.replaceAll("&ETH;", "Ð");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Ntilde;", "Ñ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Ograve;", "Ò");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Oacute;", "Ó");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Ocirc;", "Ô");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Otilde;", "Õ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Ouml;", "Ö");
            l = l.replaceAll("&OElig;", "Œ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&times;", "x");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Oslash;", "Ø");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Ugrave;", "Ù");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Uacute;", "Ú");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Ucirc;", "Û");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Uuml;", "Ü");
            l = l.replaceAll("&Yacute;", "Ý");
            l = l.replaceAll("&THORN;", "Þ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&szlig;", "ß");
            l = l.replaceAll("&agrave;", "à");
            l = l.replaceAll("&aacute;", "á");
            l = l.replaceAll("&acirc;", "â");
            l = l.replaceAll("&atilde;", "ã");
            l = l.replaceAll("&auml;", "ä");
            l = l.replaceAll("&aring;", "å");
            l = l.replaceAll("&aelig;", "æ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&ccedil;", "ç");
            l = l.replaceAll("&egrave;", "è");
            l = l.replaceAll("&eacute;", "é");
            l = l.replaceAll("&ecirc;", "ê");
            l = l.replaceAll("&euml;", "ë");
            l = l.replaceAll("&igrave;", "ì");
            l = l.replaceAll("&iacute;", "í");
            l = l.replaceAll("&icirc;", "î");
            l = l.replaceAll("&iuml;", "ï");
            l = l.replaceAll("&eth;", "ð");
            l = l.replaceAll("&ntilde;", "ñ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&ograve;", "ò");
            l = l.replaceAll("&oacute;", "ó");
            l = l.replaceAll("&ocirc;", "ô");
            l = l.replaceAll("&otilde;", "õ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&ouml;", "ö");
            l = l.replaceAll("&oelig;", "œ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&divide;", "/");
            l = l.replaceAll("&oslash;", "ø");
            l = l.replaceAll("&ugrave;", "ù");
            l = l.replaceAll("&uacute;", "ú");
            l = l.replaceAll("&ucirc;", "û");
            l = l.replaceAll("&uuml;", "ü");
            l = l.replaceAll("&yacute;", "ý");
            l = l.replaceAll("&thorn;", "þ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&yuml;", "ÿ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&yuml;", "ÿ");
            l = l.replaceAll("&quot;", "\"");
            l = l.replaceAll("&amp;", "&");
            l = l.replaceAll("&lt;", "<");
            l = l.replaceAll("&gt;", ">");
            l = l.replaceAll("&\\w{3,8};", " ");
        } // end if (l.contains("&") && l.contains(";"))

        if ((l.contains("<u+00") || l.contains("<U+00")) && l.contains(">")) {
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0021>", " !");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0022>", " \"");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0023>", " #");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0024>", " usd");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0025>", " %");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0026>", " &");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0027>", " \'");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0028>", " (");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0029>", " )");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+002[aA]>", " *");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+002[bB]>", " +");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+002[cC]>", " ,");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+002[dD]>", " -");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+002[eE]>", " .");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+002[fF]>", " /");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0030>", " 0");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0031>", " 1");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0032>", " 2");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0033>", " 3");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0034>", " 4");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0035>", " 5");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0036>", " 6");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0037>", " 7");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0038>", " 8");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0039>", " 9");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+003[aA]>", " :");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+003[bB]>", " ;");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+003[cC]>", " <");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+003[dD]>", " =");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+003[eE]>", " >");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+003[fF]>", " ?");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0040>", " @");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0041>", " A");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0042>", " B");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0043>", " C");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0044>", " D");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0045>", " E");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0046>", " F");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0047>", " G");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0048>", " H");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0049>", " I");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+004[aA]>", " J");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+004[bB]>", " K");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+004[cC]>", " L");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+004[dD]>", " M");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+004[eE]>", " N");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+004[fF]>", " O");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0050>", " P");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0051>", " Q");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0052>", " R");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0053>", " S");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0054>", " T");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0055>", " U");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0056>", " V");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0057>", " W");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0058>", " X");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0059>", " Y");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+005[aA]>", " Z");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+005[bB]>", " (");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+005[cC]>", " \\");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+005[dD]>", " )");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+005[eE]>", " ^");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+005[fF]>", " _");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0061>", " a");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0062>", " b");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0063>", " c");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0064>", " d");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0065>", " e");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0066>", " f");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0067>", " g");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0068>", " h");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0069>", " i");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+006[aA]>", " j");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+006[bB]>", " k");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+006[cC]>", " l");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+006[dD]>", " m");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+006[eE]>", " n");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+006[fF]>", " o");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0070>", " p");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0071>", " q");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0072>", " r");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0073>", " s");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0074>", " t");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0075>", " u");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0076>", " v");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0077>", " w");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0078>", " x");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+0079>", " y");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+007[aA]>", " z");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[aA]1>", " ¡");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[aA]2>", " cent");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[aA]3>", " gbf");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[aA]5>", " yen");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[aA]7>", " §");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[aA]9>", " copyright");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[aA][aA]>", " ª");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[aA][bB]>", " <<");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[aA][dD]>", " ­");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[aA][eE]>", " reg");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[bB]0>", " °");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[bB]1>", " +/-");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[bB]2>", " ^2");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[bB]3>", " ^3");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[bB]5>", " micro");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[bB]7>", " -");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[bB]8>", " ,");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[bB]9>", " ^1");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[bB][aA]>", " º");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[bB][bB]>", " >>");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[bB][cC]>", " 1/4");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[bB][dD]>", " 1/2");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[bB][eE]>", " 3/4");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[bB][fF]>", " ¿");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[cC]0>", " À");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[cC]1>", " Á");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[cC]2>", " Â");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[cC]3>", " Ã");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[cC]4>", " Ä");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[cC]5>", " Å");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[cC]6>", " Æ");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[cC]7>", " Ç");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[cC]8>", " È");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[cC]9>", " É");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[cC][aA]>", " Ê");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[cC][bB]>", " Ë");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[cC][cC]>", " Ì");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[cC][dD]>", " Í");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[cC][eE]>", " Î");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[cC][fF]>", " Ï");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[dD]0>", " Ð");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[dD]1>", " Ñ");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[dD]2>", " Ò");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[dD]3>", " Ó");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[dD]4>", " Ô");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[dD]5>", " Õ");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[dD]6>", " Ö");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[dD]7>", " ×");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[dD]8>", " Ø");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[dD]9>", " Ù");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[dD][aA]>", " Ú");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[dD][bB]>", " Û");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[dD][cC]>", " Ü");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[dD][dD]>", " Ý");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[dD][eE]>", " Þ");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[dD][fF]>", " ß");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[eE]0>", " à");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[eE]1>", " á");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[eE]2>", " â");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[eE]3>", " ã");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[eE]4>", " ä");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[eE]5>", " å");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[eE]6>", " æ");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[eE]7>", " ç");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[eE]8>", " è");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[eE]9>", " é");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[eE][aA]>", " ê");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[eE][bB]>", " ë");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[eE][cC]>", " ì");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[eE][dD]>", " í");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[eE][eE]>", " î");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[eE][fF]>", " ï");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[fF]0>", " ð");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[fF]1>", " ñ");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[fF]2>", " ò");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[fF]3>", " ó");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[fF]4>", " ô");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[fF]5>", " õ");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[fF]6>", " ö");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[fF]7>", " /");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[fF]8>", " ø");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[fF]9>", " ù");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[fF][aA]>", " ú");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[fF][bB]>", " û");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[fF][cC]>", " ü");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[fF][dD]>", " ý");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[fF][eE]>", " þ");
            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00[fF][fF]>", " ÿ");

            l = l.replaceAll("<[uU]+00\\w{2}>", "  ");
        } // end if (l.contains("<[uU]+00") && l.contains(">"))

        l = l.replaceAll("&copy", "copyright");

    }
```

i found StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(l) but it doesnt seem to prouce the same results as l.equals() was false.

What function can I use to escape those characters with a better performace (performance is very important in this case)?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: I get a HTML page in this format and need it converted that way for other operations like finding Strings in it. Getting the HTML page already in a better format isn't an option

Comment: Not sure if you will be able to use a third party lib to un-escape the html in that way... With your current code, instead of assigning back the value, I would suggest to chain the calls.  l = l.replaceAll("...","...").replaceAll("...","..."); If you are really considering performance on this, find the strings with the un-escaped format.

Answer (score 2):

You are potentially scanning the entire string several hundred times.

Don't.

Process it one character at a time to identify tokens you are interested in, and use a lookup table (HashMap) to convert each token to the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

`StringEscapeUtils` unescape methods don't support the complete list of HTML4 and HTML5 named character references, nor the complete Unicode character set (only up to U+FFFF).

For HTML unescaping, I would recommend you to use **Unbescape** [ http://www.unbescape.org ], of which I'm author. All the HTML unescaping operations you are performing can be done with Unbescape as simply as:

```
final String result = HtmlEscape.unescapeHtml(l);
```

...and it will perform only one pass on your text, instead of hundreds of them as you are doing with each `replaceAll` call.

Besides HTML unescaping, however, you are performing strange translations like `<U+0025> --> '&'` or also things like `'Ãœ' --> 'ö'`. Are these a requirement of your specific scenario? These are not HTML unescape operations... the `<U+0025>` ones are not HTML escapes and the `Ãœ` are basically wrongly-encoded strings, which problem is not how you write them but how you *read* them at the input stream (Strings in Java don't have an *encoding* -- instead encoding should be correctly set when reading them from or writing them to input/output streams).

Last, note that even among your *HTML unescaping* operations there are strange and non-standard ones, like `'&#[xX]24;' --> 'usd'` instead of `'&#[xX]24;' --> '$'`. Are these made on purpose?