# How to pass string parameter into function in button onclick event

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I run into one small problem.

```
<button onclick="foo('${some_string_param}')"></button>
```

It goes without any trouble when `some_string_param` doesn't contain apostrophe. But when it contains any apostrophe, it goes with **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier** error.

What should I change in my foo invocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `apostrophe` needs to be escaped. you can escape it through `&apos;` .

check [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) for all valid formats

You can replace occurrences of apostrophe in the controller, with

```
some_string_param.replaceAll("'", "&apos;");
```

before you set them in the request.

Read [How to escape special characters in jsp](http://java67.blogspot.sg/2012/10/how-to-escape-html-special-characters-JSP-Java-Example.html)

Comment: should be a html encoding function somewhere that OP can use, instead of manually doing it like this

Comment: do you mean I should rearrange the value of my some_string_param value? I mean, I should parse this value and replcae all apostrophes in it?

Comment: @nightin_gale you can replace all its occurrences with the `&apos;` in the server side , before passing it in the request

Comment: @SanKrish http://java67.blogspot.sg/2012/10/how-to-escape-html-special-characters-JSP-Java-Example.html

Comment: @Karthik T Can you show me how to inject jst c:out features into my function invokation? I would be very pleased)

Comment: @nightin_gale this link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986135/java-escape-html-special-chars

Comment: @nightin_gale What I was suggesting was to use `HtmlUtils.htmlEscape` to escape the string before using it as in your question

Comment: Just added it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Figured Ill write the answer instead of a long comment chain. As @SanKrish said, you need to escape characters which have significance in your code, or in html, before you can put it there. To prevent issues like you are having. The apostrophe is just one of the characters.

The cleaner way is to use `HtmlUtils.htmlEscape` to escape your string before using it.
Either

```
<button onclick="foo('${HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(some_string_param)}')"></button>
```

or

```
//Somewhere
some_string_param = HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(some_string_param);

//later in the view
<button onclick="foo('${some_string_param}')"></button>
```

I suggest the first way cuz its more obvious, but I am not sure its right syntax, cuz I dont know JSP

Edit: Seems `HtmlUtils` is from spring. If you arent using it, `StringEscapeUtils` is another alternative from apache commons.

Copied from the [linked article](http://java67.blogspot.sg/2012/10/how-to-escape-html-special-characters-JSP-Java-Example.html)

1) StringEscapeUtils from Apache's commons lang library.
2) HtmlUtils from Spring
3) Own custom method using String replace